# How to run Mathematica from a bash script file?

Tags: scripting

I would like to run a Mathematica package math-simple.m file inside of a bash script file. Howeever, when I write inside of the bash script as:

math -noprompt -script math-simple.m

I get a warning as /tmp/slurmd/job484099/slurm_script: line 21: math: command not found.

How could I make this bash slurm script recognize the math command of Mathematica ? In which of the Mathematica directories should I place this bash script so that it recognizes the math command of mathematica?

Best Regards,
Ahmet

Comment: I see that your error message refers to Slurm, a scheduler common on high performance computing platforms. Those environments often have specific and unique instructions and requirements to run each piece of software. I suggest that you consult the documentation of your HPC system, or contact its support personnel.